# Selenium WebDriver Error: invalid session id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I use Selenium WebDriver and Chrome to do feature testing in my app. I have already successfully setup multiple rails app with rspec, capybara and selenium, but I can't get why this one does not work.

Here's the problem: When I run the feature tests for the first time, it works according to plan. However, if I run it a second time, selenium crashes with the following message:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError:
>               invalid session id
>                 (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)

I might add that feature tests work perfectly in other apps, so this is not a Chrome/chromedriver compatibility issue.

I have been working on this for days now and I cannot figure out what's happening

Here's my config:

- selenium-webdriver (3.141.0)
- capybara (2.7.1)
- Chrome 74 and chromedriver 74.0.3729.6

`support/capyabara.rb`

```rb
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: { args: %w(headless disable-gpu) }
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: capabilities
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 15
```

`rails_helper.rb`

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)

require "spec_helper"
require "rspec/rails"
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
# https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)
require "devise"

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Only retry when Selenium raises Net::ReadTimeout
  config.exceptions_to_retry = [Net::ReadTimeout]
end
```

`support/database_cleander.rb`

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation

    # Seed database
    load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, type: :feature) do
    driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs = Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test

    if !driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.append_after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Stacktrace:

```
# ./spec/features/test_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:84:in `new'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:84:in `create_response'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:104:in `request'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:62:in `call'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:166:in `execute'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/oss/bridge.rb:584:in `execute'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/oss/bridge.rb:299:in `delete_all_cookies'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/options.rb:81:in `delete_all_cookies'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:102:in `reset!'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:109:in `reset!'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara.rb:331:in `block in reset_sessions!'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara.rb:331:in `reverse_each'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara.rb:331:in `reset_sessions!'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/rspec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:357:in `run'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:507:in `block in run_owned_hooks_for'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:506:in `each'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:506:in `run_owned_hooks_for'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:593:in `block in run_example_hooks_for'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:592:in `each'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:592:in `run_example_hooks_for'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:463:in `run'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:507:in `run_after_example'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:273:in `block in run'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:500:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:464:in `block in run'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:604:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:342:in `call'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.6.0/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:375:in `execute_with'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:606:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:342:in `call'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.6.1/lib/rspec/retry.rb:123:in `block in run'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.6.1/lib/rspec/retry.rb:110:in `loop'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.6.1/lib/rspec/retry.rb:110:in `run'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.6.1/lib/rspec_ext/rspec_ext.rb:12:in `run_with_retry'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-retry-0.6.1/lib/rspec/retry.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in setup'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:375:in `execute_with'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:606:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:342:in `call'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:607:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:464:in `run'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `with_around_example_hooks'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:500:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:251:in `run'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:627:in `block in run_examples'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `map'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `run_examples'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:589:in `run'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `map'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1894:in `with_suite_hooks'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block in run_specs'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:79:in `report'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `run_specs'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:87:in `run'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/bin/rspec:22:in `load'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/bin/rspec:22:in `<top (required)>'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:463:in `exec'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
# /Users/vincentrolea/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
```

EDIT

Chromedriver reuse the same session id over and over again over the tests. This is why the first time, the tests pass but if I start again, chromedriver will use the exact same session id which is what I think cause the problem. I logged Selenium's actions, and it does send DELETE so I don't understand.

```
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium -> POST session
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:9517/session | {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","version":"","platform":"ANY","javascriptEnabled":true,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":false,"nativeEvents":false,"rotatable":false},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"chrome"}]}}
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium <- {"sessionId":"b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031","status":0,"value":{"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"browserName":"chrome","chrome":{"chromedriverVersion":"74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29})","userDataDir":"/var/folders/_x/xj6qbw1n30z7pr18t52y1yjh0000gn/T/.com.google.Chrome.IyCrBu"},"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"goog:chromeOptions":{"debuggerAddress":"localhost:64888"},"handlesAlerts":true,"hasTouchScreen":false,"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"mobileEmulationEnabled":false,"nativeEvents":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platform":"Mac OS X","proxy":{},"rotatable":false,"setWindowRect":true,"strictFileInteractability":false,"takesHeapSnapshot":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000},"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":"ignore","version":"74.0.3729.131","webStorageEnabled":true}}
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium Detected OSS dialect.
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium -> POST session/b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031/url
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:9517/session/b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031/url | {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:50711/"}
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium <- {"sessionId":"b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031","status":6,"value":{"message":"invalid session id\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)"}}
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium -> DELETE session/b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031/cookie
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium <- {"sessionId":"b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031","status":0,"value":null}
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium -> POST session/b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031/url
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:9517/session/b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031/url | {"url":"about:blank"}
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium <- {"sessionId":"b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031","status":0,"value":null}
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium -> POST session/b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031/elements
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:9517/session/b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031/elements | {"using":"xpath","value":"/html/body/*"}
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium <- {"sessionId":"b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031","status":0,"value":[]}
  User log in (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Test Feature User log in
     Failure/Error: visit root_path

     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError:
       invalid session id
         (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)
     # ./spec/features/test_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 4.85 seconds (files took 11.27 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/test_spec.rb:4 # Test Feature User log in

2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium -> DELETE session/b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031
2019-05-10 08:24:53 INFO Selenium <- {"sessionId":"b8a41525be337e1a029cf574285d2031","status":0,"value":null}
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace that goes with the error

Comment: Hi Thomas, I've added the stacktrace. `test_spec.rb` is a one-line test with a single `visit root_path` command

Comment: Do you get the same error if you make the test more than just a `visit` call? Ie - add an assertion on expected content after the visit

Comment: There is an assertion in the test sorry, `expect(page).to have_content('String to match')`

Comment: Ok, and if you disable RSpec-retry  are you getting a different exception?

Comment: Nope, getting the same exception thrown

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found what went wrong.

We are using a library to cache api response during test after they are made for the first time.

The problem is, the driver sends a request to get a session id. This is why the first time the tests were passing. The library cached the response from the driver which had the same session id everytime, hence the error from chrome.

If you're using such libraries (VCR, ephemeral_response) and get similar error this is something you might want to investigate

Comment: I have this problem too but we are not using a library to cache api response. Had to roll back chromedriver/chrome versions for now. Only a problem in linux though, works fine in MacOS.

Comment: Hi Rob! We had an issue with Chrome and chromedriver v74 as well, but it was Net::ReadTimeout one. Adding `--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess` option to chromedriver as mentionned in the chromium bug report below resolved it for now

Comment: @VincentRolea. What about solution. Got the problem. whats the way out?

Comment: @sangharsh we fixed it by disabling EphemeralResponse (the lib we used for caching requests) before each feature tests and enabling it back afterwards in before/after hooks

Comment: Thanks! Adding the `disable-dev-shm-usage` option helped!

Answer (score 16):

The first thing I notice is that you're using a 3 year old version of Capybara with new versions of `selenium-webdriver`, `Chrome`, and `chromedriver`. Since `selenium-webdriver` doesn't follow SemVer expecting those to work correctly together is a stretch. You probably want to upgrade Capybara.

Often this error is caused by resource issues with Chrome. Since you appear to be running on MacOS that's not as likely as if you were running this in containers. However it wouldn't hurt to try adding the `disable-dev-shm-usage` chrome option, and/or setting the window size smaller to see if the error goes away. You could also just try a reboot.

Beyond that a couple of other potentials are

1. You have an after block registered that has already closed the session - comment out the after block and see if the issue goes away
2. A bug in chromedriver 74 (of which a few have been reported - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2885, etc) - try rolling back to chrome and chromedriver 73 to see if the issue goes away

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had already tried some of the things you advised, I'll look into the others. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: `disable-dev-shm-usage` Did it for me on my prod env. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error today and what worked for me was to downgrade the chromedriver version from latest to the version of chrome I have installed on my machine.